# MS Access all possible combinations field without duplication

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called Tbl_Employee.
There are 2 fields in this table called Emp_Name & Emp_ID.  Emp_ID is a key field.

Right now I have 4 employees in this database but this will grow with time.

I am trying to find all possible combinations of employees.

"Mark L"

"Jesse L"

"Blake P"

"Brooks A"

The Output would be something like this:

Mark L

Jesse L

Blake P

Brooks A

Mark L - Jesse L

Mark L - Jesse L - Blake P

Mark L - Jesse L - Brooks A

Mark L - Blake P

Mark L - Brooks A

Etc...

I made a query to do what I want but I cannot figure out how to filter out the duplicate records.  It also will not show just a single name.

The Query below would also have to be changed as an employee is added.

Here is my code:

SELECT Emp1.Emp_Name AS Emp1, Emp2.Emp_Name AS Emp2, Emp3.Emp_Name AS Emp3, Emp1.Employee_ID AS ID1, Emp2.Employee_ID AS ID2, Emp3.Employee_ID AS ID3, [Emp1] & "-" & [Emp2] & "-" & [Emp3] AS Expr1, [ID1] & "-" & [ID2] & "-" & [ID3] AS ID
FROM Tbl_Employee AS Emp1, Tbl_Employee AS Emp2, Tbl_Employee AS Emp3;

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @DonGeorge for the code.  I tried it as you wrote it and what I ended up with was: First it asked me for the value of T1, T2, T3 & T4.  When I just clicked through them, the result was a list of employees without any 2nd, 3rd or 4th people added.  The list was only 4 people long.  I tried adding brackets to the field names to see if this would help but it did the same thing.  The Emp_ID field is an auto number field.

Comment: that's odd.  It worked for me.  To make sure - the way to use this is to open a new query, switch to SQL view, then paste everything below into the query.  Then change to data view to see the results. T1, .. T4 are the table aliases set up in the query using the "tbl_employee as T1" phrase in the FROM section - you shouldn't need to do anything special for that to work.

Comment: Perfect!!!!  Turns out it was my mistake.  For whatever reason I did not stay consistent with the naming of my fields.  Everything is Emp_XXX except for the ID which I named Employee_ID.  I try not to make this mistake for this very reason.   Thanks for the code @DonGeorge

Comment: Welcome.  If it worked, can you accept the answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that emp_id is a number field.

```
Select Emp_name as combo
from tbl_employee

union all SELECT T1.Emp_Name & " - " & T2.Emp_Name 
FROM tbl_employee AS T1, tbl_employee AS T2
WHERE T2.emp_id > T1.emp_id

union all 
SELECT T1.Emp_Name & " - " & T2.Emp_Name & " - " & T3.emp_name
FROM tbl_employee AS T1, tbl_employee AS T2,  tbl_employee as T3
WHERE T3.emp_id > T2.emp_id 
      and T2.emp_id > t1.emp_id

union all 
SELECT T1.Emp_Name & " - " & T2.Emp_Name & " - " & T3.emp_name & " - " & T4.emp_name
FROM tbl_employee AS T1, tbl_employee AS T2,  tbl_employee as T3, tbl_employee as T4
WHERE T4.emp_id > T3.emp_id 
      and T3.emp_id > T2.emp_id 
      and T2.emp_id > t1.emp_id
```

And then you can add another block to the SQL for larger selections - 5, 6, or more per grouping.

Comment: Might be better to return four columns, using defaults for missing values, rather than a single concatenated ([1NF-violating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)) column.

Comment: I am new to posting questions on this type of forum.  @DonGeorge your answer worked perfectly.  How do I mark your answer that it worked or give you credit for the answer you gave?

Comment: @Mark - you should be able to click on the checkmark icon to the left of the answer - when you hover over it, it says "click to accept..."